# My if else statement keeps running the else part even though the condition is true for the if part

Tags: python-2.7

My if else statement keeps running the else part even though the condition is true for the if part
it gives me the following result

Enter a number :4

The number is even

The number is odd

```
y=int(raw_input('Enter a number :'))


if y%2==0:
    print('')
    print('The number is even')

else:
    print('')
print('The number is odd')
```

Comment: You forgot indent on the last line.

Answer (score 2):

The most probable reason is your indention:

```
y=int(raw_input('Enter a number :'))
if y%2==0:
    print('')
    print('The number is even')    
else:
    print('')
    print('The number is odd') # Make sure this line is well indented
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
y=int(raw_input('Enter a number :'))

if y&1: print('The number is odd')
else: print('The number is even')
```

And watch out for indentation, it has semantic meaning in python.

Answer (score 0):

As stated it's probably about your indention. Also wanted to point out that best practise to get line change is use just `print` without `('')`.